# Authenticating with mosquittopp

Tags: mosquitto, libmosquitto

I am writing a simple mqtt client which will connect with a mosquitto broker.

I have used the C++ wrapper (mosquittopp) of the mosquitto library to write the mqtt client. However, I don't know how to authenticate a client with username and password through functions provided by the mosquittopp wrapper while connecting.

I am looking for the implementation of following client-tool command with the help of mosquittopp.

```
mosquitto_pub -m "testing" -t test -u sheheryar -P coke
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the code you already have (and what you've tried) then somebody will be able to help

Answer (score 2):

You can set user and password before connecting with

```
mosquittopp::username_pw_set(sUser, sPassword);
```